# what is full form of gRPC ? is it "general" Remote procedure call OR "Google" Remote procedure call

Tags: grpc

is it "**general**" Remote procedure call OR "**Google**" Remote procedure call

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://grpc.io/about/#:~:text=gRPC%20was%20initially%20created%20by,centers%20for%20over%20a%20decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. According to the [grpc.io FAQ](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/faq/).

> What does gRPC stand for?
>
> gRPC Remote Procedure Calls, of course!

---

**Speculation time**

This is probably similar to what happened with YAML

> Originally YAML was said to mean *Yet Another Markup Language*, [...] but it was then repurposed as *YAML Ain't Markup Language*, a recursive acronym [...].
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#History_and_name)</sup>

It *might* have been either "Google" or "general" before, but then changed retroactively for marketing purposes. Therefor, you get the situation where there is no official explanation for the first letter of the acronym.